# PHPUnit hangs for 60 seconds / CPU spikes at beginning of each run

Tags: php, centos, phpunit, virtual-machine, vagrant

I recently moved my dev environment to a CentOS VM and since the move, phpunit hangs for about 60 seconds at the beginning of each run. This happens regardless of whether a single test or the whole test suite is run. Once the tests finally kick in, they only take a few seconds to complete so I doubt it's an issue with server resources as the VM has plenty of memory. I have also checked the logs and no errors seem to be occurring so I'm a little confused as to what's holding up the test suite.

When phpunit is called, the processor usage spikes massively:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND        
  6198 vagrant   20   0  900m  29m 9452 R 61.5  6.0   0:04.98 php
```

I have a fairly standard config and it's worked fine up until now on an identical setup (non-VM-based). Adding 60 seconds to the beginning of each run is becoming quite disruptive so I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue before?

PS. I should also mention that my phpunit install is done via a global composer command rather than using pear or phar. This could quite possibly be the source of the issue.

Comment: Do you have any logic in setUpBeforeClass static method in some test that depends on specific environment settings somehow?

Comment: I do yes. There are a bunch of tests that set up Elastisearch indexes according to server environment variables. But this occurs even when very basic test files with no setup are run in isolation too.

Comment: Install htop (sudo apt-get install htop) and check which processes are running and check the virtual memory

Comment: LONG SHOT: Do you have remote debugging turned on? I've noticed if I have remote debugging enabled on my server, and am not listening for it in my editor, when I run tests it spikes for 60 seconds and hangs until the xdebug connection times out.

Comment: I did have remote debugging turned on (which I didn't need) but even after turning it off and rebuilding the VM, the problem still persists. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I assume your tests run within vagrant-vm, and you mount your tests (and source) from host to guest. DiscIO might be painful slow within this setup (inside VM). Did you try to mount with different mount-options, in special nfs instead of vboxsf? See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html